# Merge two tables using common fields

Tags: sql, r, csv

I have two tables, which I need to get data from table 1 to table 2 by matching customer name & Sale date. In the first table, the name is in two columns but the other table its in one column.

```
> list(CustomerSales.CSV)
[[1]]
  CustomerFirstName CustomerLastName    SaleDate_Time InvoiceNo InvoiceValue
1         Hendricks             Eric 30-09-2015 13:00        10         5000
2              Fier          Marilyn 02-10-2015 15:30        15        18000
3           O'Brien            Donna 03-10-2015 13:30        16        25000
4             Perez           Barney 03-10-2015 16:10        17        20000
5              Fier          Marilyn 04-10-2015 11:10        18         6000
6         Hendricks             Eric 05-10-2015 14:00        19         8000


> list(ReturnSales.CSV)
[[1]]
    CustomerName    SaleDate_Time  ReturnDate_Time ReturnNo ReturnValue
1 Hendricks Eric 05-10-2015 14:00 10-10-2015 14:00        1        1000
2  O'Brien Donna 03-10-2015 13:30 15-10-2015 13:30        2        2000
3   Perez Barney 03-10-2015 16:10 12-10-2015 16:10        3        1500
4   Fier Marilyn 02-10-2015 15:30 08-10-2015 15:30        4        2000
```

The result should be a table like this.

```
list(ReturnSales.CSV)
    [[1]]
CustomerName    SaleDate_Time  InvoiceNo InvoiceValue ReturnDate_Time ReturnNo ReturnValue
1 Hendricks Eric 05-10-2015 14:00 19         8000  10-10-2015 14:00        1        1000
2  O'Brien Donna 03-10-2015 13:30 16        25000  15-10-2015 13:30        2        2000
3   Perez Barney 03-10-2015 16:10 17        20000  12-10-2015 16:10        3        1500
4   Fier Marilyn 02-10-2015 15:30 15        18000  08-10-2015 15:30        4        2000
```

Table 2 customer name & SaleDate_Time should be match with table 1 CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, & SaleDate_Time. Then combine from table 1, InvoiceNo & InvoiceValue to table 2.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for SQL Query for the above scenario then you can something like below.

```
SELECT RS.CustomerName
    ,CS.SaleDate_Time
    ,CS.InvoiceNo
    ,CS.InvoiceValue
    ,RS.Return_DateTime
    ,RS.ReturnNo
    ,RS.ReturnValue
FROM CustomerSales CS
INNER JOIN ReturnSales RS 
   ON RS.CustomerName = CS.CustomerfirstName + ' ' + Cs.CustomerLastName
WHERE RS.SaleDate_Time = CS.SaleDate_Time
```